# Can I render 3D objects in Ray Casting engines?

Tags: 3d, raycasting

I was gathering some information on the glorious Ray Casting technique. As far as I've understood it's not a complete 3D rendering, and that's why objects and NPC's are often displayed as simple sprites (I might be wrong here, of course).

Then I've stumbled upon the Dark Forces' engine by Lucas Arts, called [Jedi Game Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jedi_(game_engine)) and back in the days they were able to include fully 3D objects. Then a question arises: how did they do it? Do the objects "simply" boil down to a complex mixture of walls and floors?

Comment: Probably objects as NPCs and other things were displayed as sprites since it was easier to represent them as quads anyway without having to complicate the ray cast queries. The term istelf, _ray casting_, is broad (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_casting). Are you referring to _non-recursive ray tracing_ in this context? The very short answer to your question is a definite __yes__. The details and drawbacks are sufficient to fit in a (large) book discussing _ray tracing_ and its history and related methods.

Comment: @teodron yes, I'm definitely referring to non-recursive ray tracing, thanks for pointing that out (and thanks for the useful link too).